# Can I create a VIEW with duplicated columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I'm trying to get an exact replica out of a table. But there has to be a column that will be duplicated and renamed.

My SQL statement looks like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW VIEWNAME AS SELECT ID, ID AS "ID2" FROM TABLENAME
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that. But why are you asking if you can do it? Why not just try it?

Comment: Ow jeez, i've used the wrong table name, thanks for the help anyways...

Comment: As much as you can, avoid identifiers (column names, also table names) in double-quotes. Name your new column ID2, no need for the double-quotes.

Comment: @qwertz So really your question is "Why doesn't this work?" with a SQL statement that you were trying. It's always best to ask the actual question, instead of trying to guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: maybe your question is if you join two tables and each has the same column like "Name" can you use "name" in your view?  yes, provided you alias the tables and refrence them correctly in the select and then you also alais the column.  In oracle however it's "smart" enought to know a name exists twice so it will _# duplicate names so like Name, Name_0, Name_1, Name_2 if you have "name" from multiple source tables.  But you're better off aliasing them on your own for clairity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - yes, it is. As long as the resulting column names in the view aren't duplicated, there shouldn't be any problem.